# Method keyPressed() ignores defined method in superclass

Tags: java

I'm using the keypressed function form KeyAdapter. everything works fine, but i get a warning that says:
Method keyPressed() ignores defined method in superclass.
I don't know how to fix the warning.

Here's the line of code that i use.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you must call `super.keyPressed(e)` to fix the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my compiler/IDE doesn't show these warnings, I'm pretty sure that's because you don't call `KeyAdapter`'s `keyPressed` method. I think that this warning is very useful, because you are overriding a non-abstract method, meaning that the method is already implemented in `KeyAdapter`.

Obviously, in this case, the default implementation does nothing so you don't need to call it, however, in a different scenario, the superclass's implementation might rely on its method. Overriding it without calling it could break your superclass's code.

You can simply ignore this warning or just call the method:

```
@Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    super.keyPressed(e); //call the default implementation
    //do your own stuff
}
```

Simply adding `@Override` might remove the warning as well, because that shows that you're aware that you're overriding a method.

Comment: Thank you, had forgotten about that.
it fixed the error! :)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this was due to overriding a method from a parent class, but not calling `super.method()`.

To get rid of this, your method would look like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    super.keyPressed(e);
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, had forgotten about that.
it fixed the error! :)